# Jython ImportError: No module named urllib

Tags: jython-2.7

Just installed Jython 2.7beta3 and pip under Jython in mac os x

try to run /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7-b3/libexec/bin/pip install requests

Get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pip", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7-b3/libexec/Lib/site-packages/setuptools-11.3.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 519, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7-b3/libexec/Lib/site-packages/setuptools-11.3.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2630, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7-b3/libexec/Lib/site-packages/setuptools-11.3.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2310, in load
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7-b3/libexec/Lib/site-packages/setuptools-11.3.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2316, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7-b3/libexec/Lib/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7-b3/libexec/Lib/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six.moves.urllib import parse as urllib_parse
ImportError: No module named urllib
```

I found I can't install anything by pip under jython.
Please help me fix it, thanks.

Comment: I'm doing the same, and getting the same error, using Jython 2.7b3 on Linux Mint 17.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to use pip for Jython2.7b3.

I downloaded this:
https://github.com/jythontools/pip/tree/master

And ran the command:
Jython setup.py install

And pip is now up and running like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this problem is not solved completely. As you said, I reinstall pip. When I try to pip install, I got new error message: from . import inputstream
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 47-53: illegal Unicode character. Did you get this error?

Comment: I am not getting this error. I was able to install dango and django-jython using pip. But now I am trying to run django-admin.py and getting the "Import Error: No module named urllib"